# Visualization from a master table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Here's my base table:
[image]

I want to transform this in the form as shown in the matrix:
[image]

This has 2 columns, at the end, which require some calculation.

My end goal:

I want to make a line chart for different versions on x-axis and Have 2 calculated columns on the y-axis for a trend.

Ca anybody help me on this?

I tried lots of DAX and YouTubing but couldn't find much.

Comment: Consider breaking your question down to a specific ask - like how do I calculate X and Y. As it is now, your question is pretty broad. Share what you have tried and how far you have gotten etc... Also where is the date column in your base table?

Comment: Hi Thanks! My first step is to convert the transform the initial table to the matrix. You may ignore the date column for now.

Comment: I was able to achieve the transformation by visualizing it as a matrix but i was unable to achieve the same creating a new table using SUMMARIZE, CALCULATE and CALCULATETABLE

Comment: Why do you need to create a new Calculated Table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the following **Measures**:

```
E1 = CALCULATE( SUM('YourTable'[Session Count]), 'YourTable'[Event Name] = "E1")

E2 = CALCULATE( SUM('YourTable'[Session Count]), 'YourTable'[Event Name] = "E2")

...

E6 = CALCULATE( SUM('YourTable'[Session Count]), 'YourTable'[Event Name] = "E6")

E Total = [E1] + [E2] + [E3] + [E4] + [E5] + [E6]

AN Rate = DIVIDE( [E2] + [E3] + [E4] + [E5], [E6] )

D Rate = DIVIDE( [E1], [E6] )
```

Build your Matrix, and use the above for your `Values`.